# How to wrap route's business logic to forward to other routes?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a ui-router route `front`

My intention is that when the app goes to `front`, front will use some business logic to redirect to another route: `front.register`, `front.login`, `front.loginFirstTime`, etc.

This works the first time I visit the route (front -> front.register), but not the second time.

`front` -(auto)> `front.register` -(click)-> `front.info` -(click)-> `front` -!-> `front.register`

So the controller isn't reloaded on every go().  Ok, but how do I do this?

How can a route wrap business logic to forward to other routes?

```
angular.module('wmw').controller('Front', ['$scope', 'Global', 'User', '$state',
  function($scope, Global, User, $state) {
    $scope.Global = Global;
    $scope.User = User;

    console.log('only run on first visit');

    User.loadData()
    .then(function(routerState) {
      $state.go('front.'+routerState);
    });
  }]
);
```

User.loadData() returns a promise.  .then() runs when the data has been loaded.  `routerState` is the next place to visit.  Unfortunately this code is only run once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller of your `front` state, you could watch the current state, since you're monitoring child states of `front` you can do this with a simple watch in the front state controller:

```
angular.module('wmw').controller('Front', ['$scope', 'Global', 'User', '$state',
  function($scope, Global, User, $state) {
    $scope.Global = Global;
    $scope.User = User;

    // Save the router state.  Watch the current route
    $scope.state = $state;
    $scope.$watch('state.current.name', function (v) {
      // This runs on every view change
      if ($state.current.name === 'front') {
        User.loadData()
        .then(function(routerState) {
          $state.go('front.'+routerState);
        });
      }
    });
  }]
);
```

You would probably want to have a simple if to check whether the destination state is not the current state to prevent a redirect loop.

Comment: thanks!  I updated with the code I used to get it to work.  It still feels clunky.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Tbh I couldn't think of anything cleaner, another way would be to have a $stateChangeStart listener and execute your logic inside that, but in terms of cleanliness it's as bad as this...

Comment: I would use $stateChangeStart for now.  UI-Router 1.0 will have some really easy way of expressing this style of routing logic.